# Why does my observation of tcp connection termination in the web differ from the standard termination of the given sequence diagram?

Tags: php, http, tcp

Let's create the whole process of tcp connection establishment, http request and response and tcp connection  termination.

1. Content of my files:

/var/www/html/phplearn/send.php

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1/phplearn/do.php" method="post">
name: <input type="text" name="userName" size="12"/>
key:  <input type="text" name="PS" size="12"/>
<input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

/var/www/html/phplearn/do.php

```
<?php
$userName = $_POST["userName"];
$PS = $_POST["PS"];
echo "the name is:  ".$userName;
echo "<br>key word is:  ".$PS;
?>
```

2. Opening tcpdump with this parameters:

   sudo tcpdump -i lo host 127.0.0.1 -w /tmp/dataDst.pcap
3. Sending info with curl

   curl -d  "userName=test&PS=test_pass"  127.0.0.1/phplearn/do.php
4. Opening /tmp/dataDst.pcap  with wireshark

[image]

Process1: tcp connection establishment.

[image]

From no1 till no3,no problem.

Process2:http request and response.
no5  client send http request from port 38219 to 80 at server
no6  server send tcp signal to client
no7  server send http response to client

Process3:tcp connection termination
The process of tcp connection termination observed from tcpdump totally differ from the diagram on web.

[image]

In my observation,
no7   from client on port 38219 to server port 80 ACK
no8   from client on port 38219 to server port 80 FIN
no9   from server port 80 to client on port 38219 FIN
no10  from client on port 38219 to server port 80 ACK

From the diagram, there are two tcp packets from client to server and two tcp packets from  server to client .

From my tcpdump, there are three tcp packets from client to server and only one tcp packet from server to client.

Could you explain the cause for the difference between my observation and the sequence diagram in detail?

Comment: So to clarify: Your question is, how the connection termination according to the observed packets works? And just as a commend: You embedded the wrong picture for Connection initiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In **packet 7** the client acknowledges the recievement of the HTTP
  Response OK packet from the server. This is not pictured in your TCP-connection-closement sequence diagram as it does not belong to it, but to the normal TCP transmission.
- The client then indicates in **packet 8** that it wants to close the
  connection. Note that although the `ACK`-flag is set in this packet this does not acknowledge the recievement of any new data as the value of the `ACK`-number is the same (`194`). Check this with packet 7. There the value of the `ACK`-number was also `194`. This step corresponds to the first arrow of your diagramm.
- In **packet 9** the server acknowledges the close indication of the
  client and tells the client, that it also wants to terminate his side
  of the connection. This step corresponds to the two arrows from the server to the client of your diagramm. Your server packed this in one packet, which is clever as it saves data compared to sending two packets.
- In **packet 10** the client acknowledges, that the server does also want
  to terminate his part of the connection and the connection is
  therefore shut down on both sides. This step corresponds to the last arrow of your diagramm.

This follows exactly the sequence diagram you embedded in your question, but that the `ACK`-packet is send together with the `FIN`-packet

Note that TCP is bidirektional so the client can send to the server and the server can respond to this via the same connection. But it also allows half-closed connections. This means, although the client indicatet in packet 8, that he does not want to send anymore, he could still recieve data from the server.
But as the server does not want to send anymore data he also indicates this by his FIN packet in packet 9. I'm telling you this as you might wonder, why the Server also needs to send a FIN-packet to the client.

[image: TCP State Model]

A helpful and more detailed graphic to the state model of a TCP-connection can be found in Tanenbaum p. 532 or it is also depicted on this [lecture slides](https://www.vs.inf.ethz.ch/edu/WS0001/VS/Vorl.VNetz00_13.pdf) of ETH Zurich.

Comment: half-closed connections！